# Change flag tooltip to "Flag this post for serious problems or spam, or ask for moderator attention."

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

Please change the tooltip of the flag link under questions and answers to

> Flag this post for serious problems or spam, or ask for moderator attention.

as suggested by @Arjan [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50809/flag-button-makes-users-wary-of-asking-for-moderator-attention/50870#50870).

Answer (score 1):

changing to

> flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

> Flag this for for offensive material or spam, or ask for moderator attention